# how to know mongodb version through mongojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

```
dburl = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo";
db = require('mongojs').connect(dburl);
console.log(db.version);
```

I want to know mongodb version using mongojs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.executeDbCommand({ buildInfo : 1 }, function(err, buildinfo) {
  console.log('V', buildinfo.documents[0].version);
});
```

**EDIT**: shorter version using [`command()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#command):

```
db.command({ buildInfo : 1 }, function(err, buildinfo) {
  console.log('V', buildinfo.version);
});
```

To get a list of commands that you can execute:

```
db.command({ listCommands : 1 }, function(err, response) {
  console.log(response.commands);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, it is working fine. Can you let me know from where can i get db.executeDbCommand tutorials ?

Comment: @RohitJindal I think `executeDbCommand` is deprecated, I edited my answer to show an alternative and also a way of listing all available commands.